# Jpql двойной запрос

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-jpa

Требуется написать запрос, в котором мы получим все Calculate по условию поля state = true, при этом, чтобы связанный список Client был взят тоже по условию уже поля state клиента  state = true и был присвоен полю расчета client.
Получился примерно такой запрос, к сожалению не работает. Как правильно написать запрос?

```
  @Query("SELECT c FROM Calculate c WHERE c.state = true AND c.client =
  (SELECT cc FROM Client cc WHERE cc.state = true)")
  List<Calculate> getAllOpen();
  }
```

Сущности расчета и клиента.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "calculations")
public class Calculate {
@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Long id;

private boolean state = true;

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private List<Client> client;


public Calculate() {
}

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public boolean isState() {
    return state;
}

public void setState(boolean state) {
    this.state = state;
}

public List<Client> getClient() {
    return client;
}

public void setClient(List<Client> client) {
    this.client = client;
}
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "clients")
public class Client {
@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Long id;

private boolean state = true;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private Calculate calculate;

public Client() {
}

public boolean isState() {
    return state;
}

public void setState(boolean state) {
    this.state = state;
}

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public Calculate getCalculate() {
    return calculate;
}

public void setCalculate(Calculate calculate) {
    this.calculate = calculate;
}
}
```

Comment: А в чём вопрос-то?

Comment: попробуйте написать что то вроде такого: "SELECT calculate, client FROM Calculate calculate JOIN calculate.clients client WHERE client.state = TRUE AND calculate.state = TRUE" Вы должны получить в итоге массив из двух элементов, первый будет Calculate, второй это его отфильтрованные клиенты, Возможно где то ошибся, не могу сейчас проверить корректность запроса.

Comment: Artem, В общем ваш способ понятен, но придется после запроса добавлять для каждого счета поле клиентов, причем циклом, что может сказаться на производительности при большом объеме расчетов. Хотелось бы запрос, который вернет цельный расчет с уже заполненным полем клиентов, которые взяты по условии state=true

Comment: Mariyz dede предложил правку запроса с добавлением DISTINCT и join fetch - получается SELECT DISTINCT c FROM Calculate c join fetch c.client cl .... У меня на ORACLE это дает ошибку. Вопрос к Mariyz, а у Вас это работает и на какой БД?

Comment: Orthodox,  да работает, база MySQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Наверное, запрос должен выглядеть примерно так:

```
List<Calculate> openCalculate = 
session.createQuery("SELECT c 
                     FROM Calculate c join c.client cl
                     WHERE c.state = true  
                       AND cl.state = true")
      .list();
```